# Email Delivery and Management

Tags: linux, email

I want to setup my email such that whenever I receive an email, it gets transferred from my remote email service onto my personal linux server. I will then have bash scripts to automatically sort said email, hence why I want it on my own server. I need access to the mail on my server on three different devices. I initially was thinking POP3 to my server, and Maildir (maybe with git) on the server, with file syncing to the other devices, but it was explained to me that Maildir doesn't play nicely with multiple devices simultaneously. So my question is, what would be the best tools to:

a) transfer mail onto my personal server, such that I can write sorting scripts with bash.

b) transfer to, and read that sorted mail on my devices (linux and android)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fetchamil`, `getmail` or any other mail retrieving software of your choice. Set the poll interval to a value that suits you and then you'll have the email on your server. You can then use `procmail` to manage the new email(s) the way you like.

This would answer your a) question.

For the b) part, I use `offlineimap` to keep my email synced between my computers, but I don't use android devices.